# Yii - How to Implement Users Can Only Update and Delete Their Own Files?

Tags: php, yii

I have a relation like this:
[image: relation]

So, when I create/upload a file, it will be uploaded by a user. I want a user can only update/delete his own uploaded files. Example for deleting files, I have tried like this:

in FileController.php

```
<?php
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if($model->pengunggah=Yii::app()->user->id) // This is my modification

    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    unlink(getcwd().'/files/'.$model->nama_file);

    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}
?>
```

Then in protected/views/file/admin.php

```
array(
        'header'=>'Aksi',
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}', //'visible'=> (Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==1),
            'deleteConfirmation'=>"js: 'Are you want to delete '+$(this).parent().parent().children(':first-child').text()+ '?'",        
            'buttons'=>array(
                'update' => array(
                    'visible'=> 'Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==1',
                ),
                'view' => array(
                    'visible'=> 'Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==1',
                ),
                'delete' => array(
                    'visible'=>'Yii::app()->user->id',
                ), // This is my modification, I wanted to show delete button if the GridView is visited by a user whose have the file
            )   
    ),
```

I have tried like that, but user can still delete other's files and button delete still visible by all users. How can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `=` and `==` are two different operators. But that's just the start, you have other problems like missing `{}` after the `if` you added and the misplaced `unlink` ...

Comment: no there's no other problem, my problem still how to do users can only delete his own files

Comment: as @DCoder stated, you are missing `{}` after the if statement. Basically that check only is only for the next line without them added.

Comment: @cwhelms: And even then, the check is wrong - `if(x=y)` is **not** "if `x` equals `y`".

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding, I have tried put `==` and '{}' like above (I have edited my question), then how to hide the `delete button` when it is not visited by a user who have the file?

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
if($model->pengunggah=Yii::app()->user->id)
```

to this:

```
if($model->pengunggah != Yii::app()->user->id)
    throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
```

You are using `=` instead of `==`

And you need to change this:

```
'delete' => array(
     'visible'=>'Yii::app()->user->id',
),
```

to this:

```
'delete' => array(
     'visible'=>'$data->pengunggah == Yii::app()->user->id',
),
```

Or if you use this often, you can implement a function in the modle File

```
public function checkUserAccess(){
    return $this->pengunggha == Yii::app()->user->id;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
if(!$model->checkUserAccess())
    throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');


'$data->checkUserAcces()'
```

Comment: You should invert some of your comparisons. As it is, you're throwing an exception when the *correct* user clicks the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just build simple function return boolean result for example :

Model

```
<?php
...
public function checkAccess($if_file){
$model=Files::model()->find("if_file=:if_file and userId=:userId",array(':if_file'=>$if_file,':userId'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
if(count($model)>0){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}

}
...

?>
Now call your function in your gridview and in any another place need it.
```